How to access the currently displayed / rounded off value of a cell in Excel using office js?
How can I access the currently displayed value of a given cell range but not the actual value of that cell? For example - see this below image, where I have not increased the width of the cell enough to display the actual value which is getting rounded off. If I try to get the Range for this cell and access the values property, it gives back 12.001123. I tried the text property as well from the documentation, but it gives back the 12.001123 as well. I want to access the value that is showing up right now in the UI i.e. 12.00112


Doubtful this exists, curious your use case and likely you'll have to try hacky methods is my guess like compare cell width to text length, but not even sure how well that'd work. Probably would need a whole JS library just for all the edge cases lol

I'm afraid that there is no way to do this and likely never will be. Your add-in would have to have the same information about screen resolution, pixel size, and column width that Excel itself use to determine whether to truncate, and then it would have to go through the same calculations.
